# При проверке на реальном устройстве работает не так как надо

Tags: android, проверка, устройство

Проверял на эмуляторе на компьютере и на стандартном эмуляторе android studio - работает всё как мне нужно. А когда проверяешь на реальном устройстве происходит следующее: будто открывает тот же активити что и запущен.

это код в onCreate:

```
mIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               sub();
            }
```

это код sub(); :

```
public void sub(){
        ValueEventListener valueListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String peopleNumber = dataSnapshot.child("people").child(user.getUid()).child("bro").getValue(String.class);
                if (peopleNumber != null){
                    Toast.makeText(main_menu.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(main_menu.this,bro.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(main_menu.this, "Подписка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(main_menu.this,Bro_sub.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        mMessageDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(valueListener);
    }
```

что не так в этом коде?

Comment: как называется активити в которой выполняеться этот код?Я так понимаю что при нажатии вызывается эта же активность?

Comment: main_menu. Да, на устройстве вызывается та же активность

Comment: Версии андроида на телефоне/в эмуляторе какие?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй отдельно создай объект контекста для этой активити и передай в интент. 
Создайте отдельно контекст и передайте:

```
private Context context;
Intent intent = new Intent(context,bro.class);
```